# Going back to previous line in Spyder

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, spyder

I am using the Spyder editor and I have to go back and forth from the piece of code that I am writing to the definition of the functions I am calling. I am looking for shortcuts to move given this issue. I know how to go to the function definition (using `Ctrl + g`), but I don't know how to go back to the piece of code that I am writing. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You can use the shortcuts <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to move to the previous/next cursor position, respectively.

Comment: I'm using Windows and the problem is that my screen turns around when I do that.

Comment: Then please go to `Tools > Preferences > Keyboard shortcuts`, look for those shortcuts and change them to something that works for you.

Comment: For me it's Alt+Left or Alt+Right by default (spyder 5.4.3 on win10)

Comment: @ascripter, thanks for pointing that out, we changed that in Spyder 5. And I updated the answer accordingly.